# How to keep fixed width on outer 2 div's from 3 in a row

Tags: css, html, resize

I have been searching and trying all kinds of different stuff to make it work, but I did not succeed.

this is a link that may help to understand: http://bflydesign.no-ip.org:9876

Here is my issue: I have a centered div (width 75% and max of 1020px) that contains 3 div's: 30px - adaptive width - 30px.

The two smaller div's of 30px only contain a background (white stripes). When resizing I want the center-div to adapt but not the two outer div's. What is happening now is that the width of the outer div's is given to the center div. How can I keep the fixed width on the outer div's?

in this fiddle it seems no problem: http://jsfiddle.net/bflydesign/N3LZ9/

```
.left, .right {
min-height: 700px;
width: 30px;
min-width: 30px;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make just the 2 image `div` elements have a fixed width when you resize, you have to add the following to your `.center` class:

```
.center {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: hidden; /* <- add this */
}
```

You can do the following if you want to make it responsive:
(all three `div` elements will be properly resized.)

```
.center {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 94%;
}

.left, .right {
    height: 1000px;
    min-width: 30px;
    background-image: url('cubes_bg.png');
    width: 2.94%;
}
```

The problem here was that your contents didn't fit into your parent `div` so your images were behind the center `div`.

So if you specify your width elements correctly calculated so the total width in your parent `div` is 100%, there is no problem.

Comment: I'm glad seeing belgians here :) regards